# How can I see which filetypes a given application can open?

Tags: macos, finder, applications

I have an app, it's refusing to open a file with a certain file extension. How do I check which file extensions it *will* open?

Answer (score 1):

I think the go-to app is still [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) (freeware). Hasn't been updated since 2009... still works in Mojave.

It can list & optionally reassign any app, UTI, extension etc.

[image]